# Encoding problems in output files - C++

Tags: c++, encoding, io

The preamble of my `program.cpp` source code:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <gsl/gsl_sf_gamma.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_integration.h>
#include "program.h"
```

In `program.h` it is worth mentioning the presence of

```
HyperInterpStruct* pHIS;        

int l_index;        

static const int ni;        

int nk;
```

Constructing my `covariance` class, I first define

```
const int covariance::ni=2048;
```

then insert a function

```
void covariance::calculate_signal (HyperInterpStruct* pBIS, int L)
{
  pHIS=pBIS;
  l_index=L;


gsl_matrix* Gl=gsl_matrix_calloc(nk,ni);
calculate_G(Gl);
std::ofstream out;

  if(l_index==1)
  {
  out.open("out.txt", std::ios::out);
  }
  else
  {
  out.open("out2.txt", std::ios::out);    
  }

# pragma omp parallel for
  for (int i=0; i<nk; ++i)
  {
    for (int j=0; j<nk; ++j)
    {
      double Aij=gsl_matrix_get(Gl,i,j);
      out << i << "\t" <<  j <<  "\t" << Aij << std::endl;

    }
  }
out.close();
gsl_matrix_free(Gl);
}
```

The function to the calculate the G matrix is defined below:

```
void covariance::calculate_G (gsl_matrix* Gl)
{
 //the definition of G is too long and unnecessary to the purpose of this question. Perhaps the only thing worth mentioning is that it depends on another function, F, defined below
}

double covariance::F (double z, double k)
{
//again, the definition of F is too long and unnecessary. Perhaps the only thing worth mentioning is that it depends on another class which takes as input `pHIS` and `l_index`  
  Anotherclass anotherclass(k,pHIS,l_index);
}
```

## The problem I am facing is that my output files "out.txt" and "out1.txt" are full of strange symbols and apparently present problems with encoding and I don't know why.

I include the `main.cpp` file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "hyperspherical.h"
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{


  int nk=500;                   
  double kmin=5.e-3;            
  double kmax=1.;               

  int *l_steps;
  int number_of_l_steps = 2;
  int l_max = 500;
  int l_min = 100;
  l_steps=new int[number_of_l_steps];

  for (int i=0; i<number_of_l_steps; ++i)
  {
    l_steps[i]=l_min+i*(l_max-l_min)/(number_of_l_steps-1);
  }
  int l_bessel[2*number_of_l_steps];
  for (int i=0; i<number_of_l_steps; ++i)
  {
    l_bessel[2*i]=l_steps[i]-1;
    l_bessel[2*i+1]=l_steps[i];
  }
  double x_bessel_min = 1.e-5;
  double x_bessel_max = 1.e5;
  double sampling = 150.;
  double j_l_min=1.e-13;
  ErrorMsg bessel_error_message;
  hyperspherical_HIS_create(0,1.,2*number_of_l_steps,l_bessel,x_bessel_min,x_bessel_max,sampling,l_steps[number_of_l_steps-1]+1,j_l_min,&HIS,bessel_error_message);
  survey sv(&sd,sigma_epsilon,&ph,f_sky,l_max,cp);
  covariance cv(nk,kmin,kmax,&sv,cp,false,true);

  double zmin = 0.1;
  double zmax = 4.;
  double kmin1= 1.e-2;
  int ni = 2048;

  for(int elle = 0; elle<number_of_l_steps; elle++)
  {
         cv.calculate_signal(&HIS,2*elle+1);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is a value assigned to the variable, nk?

Comment: @BradS. I edited my question to answer yours. I forgot to include the assignment in the main.cpp

Comment: why `# pragma omp parallel for` ? You are writing to one output, by using multiple threads you are only making it slower and less predictable.

Comment: in the function, `void covariance::calculate_signal (HyperInterpStruct* pBIS, int L)`,  the two for loops that contain the `out << ...` both reference a variable, nk....where is that variable assigned a value?

Comment: @BradS. isn't it enough to assign a value to `nk` in the `main.cpp`? Maybe that is the source of error...

Comment: @johnhenry That `nk` is local to `main`. Read about scope in your favourite C++ book.

Comment: @PeterT originally this piece of code was used differently: calculations were actually performed in `calculate_signal`, inside the loop where the parallelization happens. I modified the code because I needed this output. Thanks for making me notice that the pragma slows down there. Do you think it also make it unrealiable?

Comment: @BradS., @molbdnilo even redefining the `nk` inside `calculate_signal` I still get problems with the encoding in my output file